# Why do I see dependency injection so often in the context of hosted services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, ihostedservice

I'm new to C# (and programming in general) and I've recently learned about how background tasks can be implemented using hosted services (e.g. schedule a task to fire at regular intervals). I've been reading up about associated concepts, like long-running [background services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), the [worker service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers?pivots=dotnet-6-0) template and the [Windows Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-6-0) that you can see in Task Manager.

However, what I'm struggling to understand is why dependency injection (and DI containers) constantly gets mentioned in the documentation. (See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) example about how the generic host created by HostBuilder manages DI, I think. Or, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers?pivots=dotnet-6-0), which says that worker services make you 'DI ready'.) I've recently learned what DI is (I think), in that it allows us to decouple relationships between objects, and that containers handle instantiation where there is a complex dependency hierarchy. But what I don't get is why they're so integral to service hosting that I'm constantly reading about DI. Is that because the background tasks themselves are object that get injected? Or are these background tasks represented by objects that all have a multitude of dependencies? Or is it something else?

Comment: All of the above plus Scoping. Some of the Services will be Singletons, some will be reused for a Session, some are created new for each type resolution. Not to mention Testing.

Comment: That's simply how it is done these days. DI is not a requirement for a service. But it's the standard for managing dependency's. Maybe in 20 years there are still services but DI got replaced by something else.

Comment: You can use DI in all sorts of applications, not just hosted services

Comment: Thanks for your response @Fildor-standswithMods and others. It sounds like you're suggesting that DI is so critical in how these background tasks work that Microsoft felt the need to assure developers that DI is supported.

Comment: Well, it's simply "state-of-art". And you wouldn't want to code that from scratch every time.